# How do add up an CoreData attribute to use for a FRC sectionNameKeypath value

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been told recently that you should only have one FetchResultsController per tableView. My table view has 2 sections and I need to somehow use the sectionNameKeyPath property to tell each entity which section of the table view they should be in.

What I am trying to do it added up the value of one of the attributes of my entity, and if its positive place it in section 0 and if it negative place that one in section 1.

Before I had 2 fetch requests and 2 FRCs and one of them looked something like this

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"statement.@sum.amountOwed >= 0")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.name), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    positiveFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)



    do{
     try positiveFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
     }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Is it possible to use the results of the predicate to tell which section that entity should reside in using the sectionNameKeyPath value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use one FetchResultsController.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "section.no", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "person.no", ascending: false)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]

let aRowResults = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "section.no", cacheName: nil)
```

in your table view, indexPath.section will correspond to the section's number.

Comment: Where does the calculation of the attributes (amountOwed) come into factor, so I know which section that Person should be place in?

Comment: Why not add new attributes? if (amountOwed>0), .no=0. if (amountOwed<0), .no=1